# Function to change CSS of nested submenu not working (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nested

I'm attempting to create a slide-in menu for a mobile website which has nested submenus that also slide in over the primary parent menu. This is done by editing the `right` style attribute to move each menu off & on screen.

Everything is working properly except that once I open a submenu, the function that's supposed to close the submenu is changing the CSS. The function that contains this instruction itself is executing (as evidenced by a console.log), but the line that edits the CSS is not working.

Here is the function that is having trouble:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.close-sub-menu').click(function(){
      $(this).parent().css("right", "-425px");
      console.log("this line is logging correctly");
  });
});
```

Interestingly enough, if I attempt to edit the CSS of `background-color` or `left`, it will work. But `right` will not work.

I've tried using `addClass` and `removeClass` instead, referencing the parent's class name directly instead of using `this`, and inline function calls, but none of it has seemed to work. I think it is either a scoping issue, or perhaps some interference with the parent menu. Either way, I'm not able to figure it out.

Here is a simple example of my problem in a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wk4wwfer/2/

JQuery is very acceptable.

Comment: It is absolute/relative positioned?

Comment: They are both fixed position. Since it is a menu, it ideally will be in a fixed position until it is closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$('.slide-menu-sub-parent').click` function is still firing when you click the close button.

Update your close function to be:

```
$('.close-sub-menu').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); //Prevents the click event from bubbling up and triggering the other click events registered
    $(this).parent().css("right", -425);
}
```

[Fiddle solution](https://jsfiddle.net/v9q19c3u/).

Comment: My hero. This worked perfectly. A question though, what exactly is stopPropagation stopping? The function itself is telling it to move off screen, so wouldn't the propagation of that function just make it stay off screen? And why was the `$('.slide-menu-sub-parent').click` function firing? I wasn't clicking on the div that makes it fire? I'm a little confused about that.

Comment: The moment you click the close button your mouse event trickles up the DOM to fire off any events registered to that element's parent/ancestors (which in this case includes the submenu event to open it). Technically clicking Back triggers on the `span` event, but thanks to event bubbling it will still trigger your close event as expected, even though it's registered on the span's parent. `stopPropagation` simply tells jQuery to not proceed up the DOM to the element's parent, which stops your submenu from overriding the `"right", -425` instruction with its own `"right", 0` setting.